# Favourite questions and answers from the 1st quarter of 2018

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

First quarter of 2018 has come to an end.

Following the tradition, we would ask the community again to **link your favorite questions and answers created from 1st January 2018 to 31st March 2018**.

You can search all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2018-01..2018-03) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2018-01..2018-03) posted the past quarter. Since we got 693 questions and 1k answers in the past quarter, to make your job easier, here are some data queries.

- [Questions with the most number of votes from the first quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738289/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/01/01)
- [Questions with the most number of views from the first quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738288/questions-with-most-views-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/01/01)
- [Answers with most number of votes from the first quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738290/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/01/01)

The above questions and answers are only for your hint. Feel free to mention any question or answered you enjoyed. Since this is **not a competition**, there's no need to mention one question or answer per one answer. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself which you think didn't get the appreciation they deserved.

Answer (score 6):

**FAVORITE ANSWERS:**

**Paulie_D**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86013/what-do-the-dwarves-do-with-all-of-the-diamonds-that-they-mine/86014#86014) to "What do the dwarfs do with all of the diamonds that they mine?"

**Memor-X**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86278/how-did-all-these-monuments-end-up-together-in-one-place/86279#86279) to "How did all these monuments end up together in one place?"

**AJ**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85751/how-were-opening-titles-and-end-credits-created-before-computers/85752#85752) to "How were opening titles and end credits created before computers?"

**Tinkeringbell**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85353/making-nature-documentaries-scripting-then-filming-or-the-other-way/85354#85354) to "Making nature documentaries: scripting then filming or the other way?"

Answer (score 5):

All these questions and answers are my favorite ones.

1. [Napoleon Wilson](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/49/napoleon-wilson)'s [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/84880/27264) to [**Is the title “The Last Jedi” singular or plural?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/84846/27264) asked by [mzywiol](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/7172/mzywiol).
2. [Chris John](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/34108/chris-johns)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/85562/27264) to [**Why was Bruce Wayne so harsh/rude when he asked for everyone to leave his party?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/85556/27264) asked by [Metro Boomin](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/51747/metro-boomin).
3. [Tetsujin](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/25773/tetsujin)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/85877/27264) to [**What is this type of scene transition called?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/85869/27264) asked by [Christina](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/62095/christina).
4. [Tetsujin](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/25773/tetsujin)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/84653/27264) to [**Black Mirror - clever writing or me being cynical?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/84652/27264) asked by [Tim B James](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/60205/tim-b-james).
5. [Charles](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/31426/charles)'s [**question**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/84563/27264) and its answers are my favorite.

Answer (score 5):

**FAVORITE QUESTIONS:**

**Nogshine**'s question: [What is the importance of the coffee cup in the poster of awe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87573/what-is-the-importance-of-the-coffee-cup-in-the-poster-of-awe)

**R. Cannon**'s question: [What does "There came into Egypt a Pharaoh that did not know" mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86378/what-does-there-came-into-egypt-a-pharaoh-that-did-not-know-mean)

**G.Byatt**'s question: [What do the dwarves do with all of the diamonds that they mine?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86013/what-do-the-dwarves-do-with-all-of-the-diamonds-that-they-mine)

**Nathaniel D. Hoffman**'s question: [Who is the first impression when Robin Williams is becoming Mrs. Doubtfire?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85790/who-is-the-first-impression-when-robin-williams-is-becoming-mrs-doubfire)

**Thunderforge**'s question: [Did Fantasy Island have a spinoff aimed at children?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85006/did-fantasy-island-have-a-spinoff-aimed-at-children)

**Johnny UX**'s question: [Did Danny Noonan go on to play pro golf?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84915/did-danny-noonan-go-on-to-play-pro-golf)